# pandas: how can I get the data of the line that I want?

Tags: python, pandas

There are some data about films.
These files contain 1,000,209 anonymous ratings of approximately 3,900 movies 
made by 6,040 MovieLens users who joined MovieLens in 2000.(See Picture)

I got 3 DataFrame from these data: **movies ratings**  and  **usrs**

[movies DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFpRQ.png)

[ratings DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGwcl.png)

[usrs DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH3L6.png)

As you can see , **F** in usrs DataFeame means Female.

#### How to find the movies that female likes most?(top 10)

Now I got the **UserID** of Female users from ***usr DataFrame**, but I don't konw how to get **MovieId** and **Rating** from **rating DataFrame** according the UserID that I got before.

[Female_user_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txYtb.png)

How can I slove the problem?   Tanks very much if anyone can help me.

Comment: ratings.loc(ratings.UserID.isin(female_usrid))['MovieID'] ,,,,,, ratings.loc(ratings.UserID.isin(female_usrid))['Rating']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dataframe.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function to join all the three table and apply groupby or pivot_table to get the top 10 movies that females like.